# Lazy loading imageView on listView

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, lazy-loading

I've been having problems with this for quite some time now. I'm getting there little by little but I don't have much time to spend programming :(

So I'm having to load image from URLs for showing on a list view, and i'm almost there. They are lazy loading and the cache system i'm using works good.
The problem is that the downloaded images are in the wrong place when I start scrolling and I can't figure out where i'm going wrong.

The code is inspired from these two links:
This one for the layout idea.
http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/
and this one for the cache system.
http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

So here's my **code**:

```
public class LoaderImageView extends LinearLayout
{

private static final String TAG = "LoderImageView";

private Context mContext;

private ImageView mImage;
private ProgressBar mSpinner;


/* The HashMap that contains the references to the different 
 * downloads currently running.
 */
public static HashMap<LoaderImageView, BitmapDownloaderTask> tasks =
        new LinkedHashMap<LoaderImageView, BitmapDownloaderTask>();

public LoaderImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;

    mImage = new ImageView(mContext);
    mImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mSpinner = new ProgressBar(mContext);
    mSpinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);


    addView(mSpinner);
    addView(mImage);

    Log.w(TAG, "Loading an imageView");
}

public void downloadImage(String url)
{
    resetPurgeTimer();

    //Log.w(TAG, "Loading: " + url);

    if(url.equals(""))
    {
        mImage.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.male));
    }
    else
    {

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(url);

        if(bitmap == null)
        {
            /* The bitmap is not in the cache. */
            cancelPotentialDownload(this);

            /* Start the new download. */
            BitmapDownloaderTask bdt = new BitmapDownloaderTask(this, url);
            bdt.execute();
        }
        else
        {
            /*The bitmap is in the cache. */
            mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}

class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private String mUrl;
    private LoaderImageView mLiv;

    public BitmapDownloaderTask(LoaderImageView liv, String url)
    {
        mLiv = liv;
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        LoaderImageView.tasks.put(mLiv, this);
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.w(TAG, "Starting an AsyncTask");
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        URL url = null;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(mUrl);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return BitmapTools.fetchBitmap(url);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapDownloaderTask b = tasks.get(mLiv);

        if(b == this)
        {
            LoaderImageView.tasks.remove(this);
            mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        if (isCancelled())
        {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        addBitmapToCache(mUrl, bitmap);
        tasks.remove(mLiv);
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

/* More methods related too the cache... */

Here the **xml** layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector" >

    <com.myproject.liste.LoaderImageView
        android:id="@+id/visites_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm creating the list with a BaseAdapter and ListActivity.
Also i'm loading the list by pages of data: I load 10 items, when the user scrolls down I load 10 more, and call notifyDataSetChange();

Comment: Tried using https://github.com/thest1/LazyList ? I tried programming this kind of stuff myself but LazyList is super configurable and works like a charm.

Comment: Can we see your adapter code? If you are recycling your views (as you should be!) then by the time an image has downloaded - the view may have been re-used for a different row so the image will be incorrect

Comment: This looks good. In the getView() method can I inflate my own layout and use the ViewHolder pattern ? And also I realy wanted the spinner when the image is downloading.
@Kingraam: Yep the view are recycled. But in the onPostExecute of my asyctask, I should be avoiding that. (?)

Comment: Don't exactly understand  what you mean but you can use you a custom layout for the rows and you can use a spinner in the back of an epmty image (relative layout) and hide it when the image is loaded, just remove the stub (i think it is in ImageLoader.java) and replace it for the spinner.

Comment: Damn, I meant ProgressBar (the spinning one).

Comment: It's weird I'm still getting the same problems. Does anybody know about a project that does what I want with LazyList ? Or any other project I can take a look at.
Also i'm loading the list by pages of data: I load 10 items, when the user scrolls down I load 10 more, and call notifyDataSetChange();